# How does matplotlib classify the training examples and plot them in the code given below and how does the code work?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, classification

This is a classification bases logistic regression problem.
X consists of data in the form of :

```
array([[34.62365962, 78.02469282],
       [30.28671077, 43.89499752],
       [35.84740877, 72.90219803]
       .......
```

where the first column is score in the first exam and the second column is score in the second exam.

y is a data in which '1' signifies the student got into university, and '0' represents the student did NOT get into university(based on their first and second exam score given in X).

```
array([0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.,
       0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.,
       0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 0.
```

The code to plot a following data is :

```
pos = y == 1
neg = y == 0
# Plot Examples
pyplot.plot(X[pos, 0], X[pos, 1], '*', lw=2, ms=10)
pyplot.plot(X[neg, 0], X[neg, 1], 'o', mfc='y', ms=8, mec='k', mew=1)
```

I do not understand how does `pos = y == 1`  and `neg = y == 0`  work to plot the data as x-axis and y-axis values given by `X[pos, 0], X[pos, 1]` and `X[neg, 0], X[neg, 1]`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `==` creates a bolean arary i.e an array of `True` or `False`, e.g:

```py
import numpy as np
y = np.array([1,0,1,1,0,0])
print(y==1) # [True,False,True,True,False,False]
```

you can then use this True/False array (also known as a "mask") to filter your array. Say for instance you have the following:

```py
y = np.array([0.5,1,-3,4,0])
pos = y>0 #[True,True,False,True,False]
```

if you then "slice" using the mask, it only returns the value where the array is True:

```py
y = np.array([0.5,1,-3,4,0])
pos = y>0 #[True,True,False,True,False]
print(y[pos]) #[0.5,1,4]
```

With that in mind you can see that

```py
pos = y==1
neg = y==0
```

creates two masks; one for all the places where y is equal to 1, and one for all the places where y is equal to 0.

Since the first row of `X` corresponds to the first row of `y` we can use the mask to slice both `X` and `y` e.g

```py
pos = y==1
neg = y==0

X_pos = X[pos] #All the x-values where y==1
y_pos = y[pos] # All the y-values where y==1

X_neg = X[neg] #All the x-values where y==0
y_neg = y[neg] # All the y-values where y==0
```

and then you can plot those two groups.

They have done it implicit just by using

```py
X[pos,0] #correponds to first column in our X_pos above
X[neg,0] #correponds to first column in our X_neg above
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but I'll try answering..

```
pos = (y == 1)
```

(I've added the parenthesis so it'll be clearer) What actually happens here, is that pos is assigned with something of this form:

```
[True, True, False, .....]
```

where each `True` correspond to an index which `y` had `1` in, same goes for `neg` only for `0`.

Now when you use `X[pos, 0]`, it returns an array only consist of the lines of `X` when `pos` had a `True` value in the corresponding index, therefore -  `X[pos, 0]` is the X axis of passed students and `X[pos, 1]` is the Y axis of passed students

Comment: I have never encountered this type of list function (```X[pos, 0]```). What is it called ?

Comment: I see @CutePoison answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69447326/5353753 has covered everything..